# a .net application deployment issue. is thinapp a solution?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, vmware, setup-deployment

First i want to clear that i am in very big trouble. I developed application without doing any research.I spent 3 month in developing that project .This project uses vs2010,vs2010 report viewer, .net 3.5sp1, ms sql server 2005 , sql3.5 compat addition.

all of my customers are xp sp2 users. none of them have xp sp3. so i cant use .net4. and installation of all these takes at least 30 min. in clients machine. I think that could affect my business.

I have googled this problem but i found nothing that could help me to shorten installation time.I also want to say that i am not using any extra feature. I can easly go back to .net 2.0 or .net 3.0. but for vs2010 report viver i have to use .net3.5 sp1. so i am stuck actually.

then i came to know that thinapp can be a solution. But can i use thinapp to bundle.net 3.5 sp1 and sql server 2005? will it work? if not then pls give me some other solution. I am stuck in middle

Answer (score 2):

There may be various things you can do...

First of all set the project build option to .Net 2.0 in Visual Studio 2010 to be sure it will run on an old XP version.

Secondly, I think you should be able to use the report viewer from here:  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21916 instead of the one that comes with VS 2010 (notice that the requirements on that link are .net 2.0).  It may not have all the features but it should work.

Then make it all compile which may be hard depending on how you have written your code, but maybe not, just as an aside...

If you are using anything from the System.Linq namespace there is a library called [LinqBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) that you can use which means you will not have to change any of that code at all.

I'd give those few things a go and then if you have specific problems back-porting your code you could ask more specific questions.

Comment: when i changed it to .net 2.0 it gives me error" .net 2.0 the type or namespace name objects does not exist in the namespace system.data"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785820/error-in-converting-net-3-5-project-to-net-2-0-need-a-solution

Comment: From looking at your other question it sounds like you have some entity framework code to convert too.  I agree with the answer you got - I think you will have to rewrite it in regular ado .net.